# Classic ASP pass object attribute to SOAP

Tags: soap, asp-classic

We have a Java Web Service (WSDL) and a ASP Client. We are using SOAP Toolkit 3.0 to make calls to the Java web service. The Java web service is exposing objects, so I need to use complex type mappers.

When I am trying this, I am getting the error -

```
SoapMapper:Saving SoapMapper account failed HRESULT=0x80004002: No such interface supported - Client:Unspecified client error. HRESULT=0x80004002: No such interface supported
```

The code for this is:

```
On Error Resume Next

Dim objWebSvcClient
Dim  strSuccess
Dim myaccount

set objWebSvcClient = server.CreateObject("MSSOAP.SoapClient30")
objWebSvcClient.ClientProperty("ServerHTTPRequest") = True
objWebSvcClient.MSSoapInit ("c:\TestAsp.wsdl")


class Account
    Dim maccid 'As String
    Dim maccName 'As String

    Public Property Get accId() 'As String
        accId = maccid
    End Property

    Public Property Let accId(ByVal Value )
        maccid = Value
    End Property

    Public Property Get accName() 'As String
        accName = maccName
    End Property

    Public Property Let accName(ByVal Value )
        maccName = Value
    End Property
End class

Set myaccount = new Account
myaccount.accId = "ABC"
myaccount.accName = "ABC"

strSuccess = objWebSvcClient.setAccount(myaccount)
```

Please let me know If I am missing out some Information.

Reference to some examples doing the same implementation would also be helpfull.

Comment: which line in this code do you see the error? And to properly debug it, remove `on error resume next` statement.

Comment: strSuccess  = objWebSvcClient.setAccount(myaccount) I am getting error on the above line. I am passing the object attributes to this method. So I dont know how should I pass the object to the method.

Comment: I really thanful  to thevikas that he at least replied because I want to get me out from this as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

the statement `objWebSvcClient.MSSoapInit ("c:\TestAsp.wsdl")` is setting a physical file as a URL. You can parse WSDL this way but the URLs given in the wsdl itself may not working or are with relatively path which will fail.

Try giving the full http url even for the wsdl file.

Comment: URL : http://query.jiemai.com/services/UsJieMaiSlService?wsdl and in that case I need to pass ProductCondition Object with different attributes and I am getting the same error You can see the parameters here http://soapclient.com/soapclient?template=%2Fclientform.html&fn=soapform&SoapTemplate=%2FSoapResult.html&SoapWSDL=http%3A%2F%2Fquery.jiemai.com%2Fservices%2FUsJieMaiSlService%3Fwsdl&_ArraySize=2